# Не работает запрос PDO (INSERT/ SELECT)

Tags: php, pdo, insert

Я начал изучать и PHP, и ASP.NET, пока что у меня в голове каша..
**ОС:** Ubuntu 18.04
**Сервер:**  Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)/

```
Server built:   2018-10-10T18:59:25
```

**PHP:**    PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
**MySQL:** mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25
**phpmyadmin**:  4.8.5

Содержание index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <? require "add.php";?>
</body>
</html>
```

А внутри ***add.php*** расположен след. код:

```
<form action="controller.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="theme"><br/><br/>
        <textarea name="text"  cols="60" rows="13" placeholder="Введите текст статьи"></textarea><br/><br/>
        <button type="submit" >addDB</button>
</form>
```

А внутри ***controller.php*** расположен следующий код:

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost; dbname = input_db", "root", "123");

    $sql = ("INSERT INTO tables (theme, text) VALUES (:theme, :text)");

    $statment = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statment -> bindParam(":theme", $_POST['theme']);
    $statment -> bindParam(":text", $_POST['text']);
    $statment -> execute();
```

Вроде всё кажется правильным, но почему-то в базу не добавляет введенные данныею

И еще как сделать так, чтоб при нажатии, на кнопку **AddDB** и отправил запрос,и потом возвращался на главную страницу?

Comment: вы хоть какой-то дебаг делали ? ошибки выдает в логе ?

Comment: xdebug установил. Ошибка никак нету, пустая страница отображается, но и не добавляется на базу..

Comment: сделайте вывод $_POST а начале файла controller.php
var_dump($_POST); die;

Comment: и еще где-то прочитал, что xdebug не все ошибку отображает.. При не правильном подключении в базу, xdebug отображает ошибку.  Возможно такие частые ошибки только отображает, видимо .. Вот так вот..

Comment: Я вардампил, все получает из фоормы, но дальше не отправляет..

Comment: /var/www/html/input/controller.php:3:
array (size=2)

  'theme' => string 'Тема статьи' (length=21)

  'text' => string 'Какой-то текст...' (length=29)

Comment: ну тогда что-то с подключением

Comment: try {
   $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost; dbname = input_db", "root", "123");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

Comment: пробовал, все нормально подключился, вардампил даже, нормально..
object(PDO)[1]   вывел..  может у меня проблема с phpmyadmin?
А на счет верхнего кода, все так да, нормально все, правильно все сделал??

Comment: madfan41k, если у вас есть возможность, можете себе пробовать запустить мой код..

Answer (score 4):

Это очень хорошй и важный вопрос.
Но ответ на него не совсем очевидный. И звучит он так: "Надо правильно соединяться с PDO".

Вообще, тема "что делать, если код не работает" довольно обширная, но самое первое, что надо делать в таком случае - это попросить РНР **сообщать обо всех ошибках**, которые произошли в скрипте.

Плюс, в данном случае - попросить PDO сообщать об ошибке, произошедшей при выполнении запроса. И вот как раз для этого и надо правильно соединяться: [Как правильно соединяться с Mysql в PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). Помимо других важных настроек мы таже сконфигурируем правильный режим выброса ошибок для PDO.

После этого PDO само начнет нам сообщать, с какой проблемой оно столкнулось! Надо только убедиться, что [PHP в принципе настроен так, чтобы сообщать об ошибках](http://phpfaq.ru/debug).

```
<?php

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=input_db;charset=utf8mb4";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, "root", "123", $options);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tables (theme, text) VALUES (:theme, :text)";
$statment = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statment -> bindParam(":theme", $_POST['theme']);
$statment -> bindParam(":text", $_POST['text']);
$statment -> execute();
```

Скорее всего PDO сообщит о том, что не найдена база данных или хост, поскольку **никаких украшений** (включая пробелы) в DSN быть не должно.

Но конкретная ошибка в данном случае не важна, поскольку ошибки всегда разные, и на все случаи все равно ответить невозможно. Но это и не нужно - надо просто прочитать сообщение об ошибке, и исправить её.

Comment: Все сработала, Спасибо огромное  Ипатьев и  madfan41k.. 
там только $dsn добавить внутри try перед "root"..
Спасибо, огромное еще раз.. 
Я еще вернусь, (I all be back) ;)