# Проблема с запросом на удаление (DELETE)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

При отправке запроса возвращает false (4 строка снизу где запрос на удаление)

```
<?php
session_start();
    $main = new MainClass();
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'u91108o2_db';
    $db = 'u91108o2_db';
    $pass = 'roooot';

    $main->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);

    class  MainClass {
        function db_e($sql){
            $result = $this->connect->exec($sql);
            return $result;
        }

        function db_q ($sql)
        {
            $result = $this->connect->query($sql);
            return $result;
        }

        function get_posts(){
            $result = $this->db_q("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `post_id` DESC");
            $res = "";
            foreach ($result as $row)
            {
                $res .= "
                    <div class='post'>
                          <h1>".$row["post_name"]."</h1>
                          <input onclick='delete_post(this)' class='del_button hide' type='button' id='".$row["post_id"]."' value='Удалить'> 
                          <img width=\"100\" src='img/".$row["post_img"]."'>
                          <p>".$row["post_text"]."</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                ";
            }
            return $res;
        } 

        function create_post()
        {
            if (empty($_SESSION['login']))
            {
                return;
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['login'] != true)
            {
                return;
            }
            $post_name = $_POST['name'];
            $check_name = $this->db_q("SELECT * FROM `table`");
            foreach ($check_name as $name)
            {
                if ($name['post_name'] == $post_name)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            $post_text = $_POST['text'];
            $name = explode(".", $_FILES['img']['name']);
            $img_type = $name[count($name) - 1];
            $new_image_path = "../img/".md5($_POST['name'].$_FILES['img']['name']).".".$img_type;
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $new_image_path))
            {
                die;
            }
            else
            {
                $img = md5($_POST['name'].$_FILES['img']['name']).".".$img_type;
                if ($this->db_e("INSERT INTO `table`(`post_name`, `post_text`, `post_img`) VALUES ('$post_name','$post_text','$img')"))
                {
                    echo "success";
                }
            }
        }

        function login()
        {
            $_SESSION['login'] = false;
            $users = $this->db_q("SELECT * FROM `user`");
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                if ($user['nick'] == $_POST['login']) {
                    if ($user['hash'] == md5($_POST['pass'])) {
                        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $_SESSION['login'];
        }
    }

    ####################################################################
    ####################################################################
    ######################## Вызов принят XD ###########################
    ####################################################################
    ####################################################################
    if (isset($_POST['get_posts']))
    {
        echo $main->get_posts();
    }
    if (isset($_POST["create"]))
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['text']) && !empty($_FILES))
        {
            $main->create_post();
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['auth']))
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['pass']))
        {
            echo $main->login();
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
       // echo "success";
        //if (
            $id = $_POST["id"];
            $id *= 1;
            var_dump($main->db_e("DELETE * FROM `table` WHERE `post_id` = $id"));//)
        //{
            echo "success";
        //}
    }
```

Comment: если вернулся false, значит была ошибка БД, которую можно получить у errorinfo http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php Но лучше глобально настроить сообщения об ошибках https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950424/194569

Comment: Помимо прочего, в обязательном порядке нужно использовать prepare()/execute() вместо exec()