# Добавление данных в таблицу SQL через PHP

Tags: php

При выполнении скрипта получаю ошибку, думаю что ошибка в этой строке кода. Данные скрипт получает с отсылаемой формы и выдает ошибку, скорее всего неправильно записал, помогите найти ошибку.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Data (Name, Description,Photo,Buy,Sell) VALUES ('"$_POST['name']"','"$_POST['description']"','"$_POST['photo']"','"$_POST['buy']"','"$_POST['sell']"'"));
```

Comment: Ошибка секретная какая-то, да?

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500 Ошибка

Comment: На кавычки внимание обратите. И код надо писать в редакторе с подсветкой синтаксиса.

Comment: В редакторе все нормально , но почему то не работает

Comment: Когда у вас 500 ошибка то в логах веб сервера есть все подробности. А вообще никогда так не пишите. Используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку переменных. Тогда никаких проблем с кавычками возникать не будет, так как не будет ни каких кавычек. Кроме того вас тогда не взломают через 5 минут после того как этот код окажется в интернете. См. примеры тут http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Если редактор блокнот - то да, в нем все нормально.

Comment: Самое удивительное, что в вашем коде нет ни одной точки. А конкатенация строк в php это оператор `.`. Нельзя в php взять и написать `print "hellow "  "world"` и ожидать, что не будет синтаксической ошибки

Answer (score 2):

Запросы в базу данных следует выполнять с помощью подготовленных выражений. 
Для этого лучше всего использовать класс PDO.

Выполнение запросов на вставку с помощью подготовленных выражений происходит в 2 стадии:

- подготовка запроса, при этом на место всех переменных ставятся знаки вопроса. При этом создается переменная $stmt.
- выполнение запроса, при котором все участвующие в запросе переменные отправляются отдельно, в виде массива, в метод `$stmt->execute()`.

в итоге код получается аккуратным и безопасным:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Data (Name, Description,Photo,Buy,Sell) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$_POST['name'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['photo'], $_POST['buy'],$_POST['sell']]);
```

Также можно посмотреть другие [примеры запросов с использованием подготовленных выражений](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples)

Хочу отметить, что данный подход гарантирует нас от ошибок синтаксиса. Однако при выполнении запроса могут возникать и другие ошибки. Это совершенно нормальная ситуация, и в случае возникновения ошибки надо просто прочитать её текст ,понять в чем она заключается, и исправить.

Чтобы ПДО всегда сообщал об ошибких, надо писать код соединения так, как написано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950424/179379)