# Проблема добавления новых записей из формы в саму базу данных phpMyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Сделали подключение к базе данных, форму, проверили, что эта форма отдаёт значения, но в самой базе новых записей не появляется, как бы не старались, ничего не получается.
Не могли бы вы подсказать, в чём может возникнуть проблема?

#### Файл db.php

```
<?php
        $user = 'root';
        $password = 'root';  
      try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=baza1", $user, $password);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
```

#### Файл api.php

```
    <?php
function getChastById($db, $id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chast
    WHERE id_chast = :id_chast 
    ";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue('id_chast', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $row;
}

function getAllDivizii ($db) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM diviziya";
    $res = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $res[$row['id_divizii']] = $row;
    }
    return $res;
}

function getAlldislokatsii ($db) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dislokatsiya";
    $res1 = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $res1[$row['id_dislokatsii']] = $row;
    }
    return $res1;
}
function getAllcorpusa ($db) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM corpus";
    $res2 = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $res2[$row['id_corpusa']] = $row;
    }
    return $res2;
}
function getAllArmii ($db) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM armiya";
    $res3 = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $res3[$row['id_armii']] = $row;
    }
    return $res3;
}
    function addChast($db, $chastId, $nomerChasti, $diviziyaId, $dislokatsiyaId, $nomerCorpusa, $nomerArmii) {
        $sql =  $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `chast` (`id_chast`, `nomer_chasti`, `kod_diviziya`, `kod_dislokatsiya`, `kod_corpusa`, `kod_armii`) VALUES(:id_chast, :nomer_chasti, :kod_diviziya, :kod_dislokatsiya, :kod_corpusa, :kod_armii)");
        $sql->bindValue(':id_chast', $chastId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->bindValue(':nomer_chasti', $nomerChasti, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->bindValue(':kod_diviziya', $diviziyaId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->bindValue(':kod_dislokatsiya', $dislokatsiyaId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->bindValue(':kod_corpusa', $nomerCorpusa, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->bindValue(':kod_armii', $nomerArmii, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->execute();
    }
```

#### Файл chast.php

```
...
        <?php include 'db.php'; ?>
                <?php include 'api.php'; ?>
        <div>

            <button id="addButton" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 15px">Добавить новую запись</button>

            <form action="" method="POST" role="form" style="display: none; margin-top: 20px;">

            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="">id части</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chastId" name="chastId">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="">Номер части</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomerChasti" name="nomerChasti">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="">Дивизия</label>
              <select id="diviziyaId" name="diviziyaId" class="form-control">
                <?php
                $divizii = getAllDivizii($db);
                foreach ($divizii as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<option value=".$value['id_divizii'].">".$value['nazvanieDivizii']."</option>";
                }
                ?>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="">Дислокация</label>
              <select id="dislokatsiyaId" name="dislokatsiyaId" class="form-control">
                <?php
                $dislokatsii = getAlldislokatsii($db);
                foreach ($dislokatsii as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<option value=".$value['id_dislokatsii'].">".$value['nazvanieDislokatsii']."</option>";
                }
                ?>
              </select>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="">Код корпуса</label>
              <select id="$nomerCorpusa" name="$nomerCorpusa" class="form-control">
                <?php
                $corpusa = getAllcorpusa($db);
                foreach ($corpusa as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<option value=".$value['id_corpusa'].">".$value['nomer_corpusa']."</option>";
                }
                ?>
              </select>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
              <label for="">Код армии</label>
              <select id="$nomerArmii" name="$nomerArmii" class="form-control">
                <?php
                $armii = getAllArmii($db);
                foreach ($armii as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<option value=".$value['id_armii'].">".$value['nomer_armii']."</option>";
                }
                ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 15px;">Добавить</button>
        </form>
        </div>

        <?php
        var_dump($_POST);
            $chastId = $_POST['chastId'];
            $nomerChasti = $_POST['nomerChasti'];
            $diviziyaId = $_POST['diviziyaId'];
            $dislokatsiyaId = $_POST['dislokatsiyaId'];
            $nomerCorpusa = $_POST['nomerCorpusa'];
            $nomerArmii = $_POST['nomerArmii'];
        ?>
        <script>
                $("#addButton").click(function(){
                    $("form").slideDown();
                });
            </script>
    ...
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает PHP (PDO/ INSERT/ SELECT)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950398/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-php-pdo-insert-select)

Comment: Включить информирование об ошибках, получить ошибку, прочесть и исправить