# У меня не обновляется запись в базе. Все происходит успешно, ошибок никаких нет, но запись не обновляется

Tags: php, mysql

Как посмотреть запрос, который executится после prepare?
Вот код:

```
public function edit($data)
{

    $login = $data['login'];
    $password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $id = $data['id'];

    $st = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET login = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $st->bindParam(1, $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $st->bindParam(3, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $st->execute();

}
```

Comment: Нативно - никак. Только создать свою функцию, которая подставит вместо плейсхолдеров значения.  Только зачем это надо? Вы же итак видите свой запрос

Comment: А дело в том, что у меня не обновляется запись в базе :/ Все происходит успешно, ошибок никаких нет, но запись не обновляется :/

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php   ,https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php  ,  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482

Comment: Включить General Log на сервере MySQL. Там и можно увидеть, что именно приходит на него от клиентского приложения.

Comment: Используй [PDOStatement::debugDumpParams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php)

Answer (score 0):

Если "запрос не работает", это может быть вызвано следующими причинами:

- **До выполнения запроса дело вообще не дошло,** из-за некорректной логики в коде программы. Чтобы это проверить, надо добавить временный отладочный вывод (или использовать пошаговую отладку в IDE)
- **При выполнении запроса произошла ошибка**. Необходимо настроить РНР так, чтобы он сообщал обо всех ошибках, в том числе при работе с БД. См. рекомендации в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950424/179379).

В случае, если запрос был выполнен, и при этом без ошибок, но при этом не сделал то что нужно, причины могут быть следующие:

- Не было найдено совпадение в условии WHERE. Надо проверять входящие данные, и данные, которые лежат в БД.
- Если запрос на изменение данных, то иногда бывает, что результат запрса проверяют *не в той базе данных*. Например, phpmyadmin работает с БД, которая настроена на порт 8889, а РНР работает с БД на порту 3306. Надо убедиться, что результат запроса проверяется в той же самой БД.
- Как вариант, изменения происходят в рамках открытой транзакции, которой потом не делают commit. Надо убедиться, что транзакция не стартует или что она подтверждается.

Для данного случая можно предложить настроить РНР и PDO, чтобы они информировали программиста об ошибках, как оказано по ссылке выше, и добавить следующий отладочный код:

```
var_dump($login, $password, $id);
$st = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET login = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?");
$st->bindParam(1, $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindParam(3, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->execute();
die("Запрос выполнен");
```

И смотреть на то, что он выведет.

- если ничего не выведет, то значит этот метод даже не был вызван. Гадо добавлять отладочный вывод выше по коду и разбираться с логикой. Например, код проверяет какой-то параметр из формы, а он не пришел, или написан с опечаткой
- если выведет ошибку, то прочитать и исправить её
- если выведет id, то проверить, есть ли такое значение в БД

После решения проблемы добавленные строки убрать.